# jQuery Countdown - Event when countdown ends

Tags: jquery, countdown

Im using the code below to display a countdown timer on a webpage. If possible, how can I show content when the count down reaches zero?

Regards

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/countdown.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "09 november 2012 12:00:00",
        format: "on"
    },
    function() {
        // callback function
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: There's a gazillion countdown plugins, maybe supplying a link to the one you're using would help ?

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/adding-a-jquery-countdown-plugin-to-our-coming-soon-page/?search_index=1

Comment: You have it right, add whatever code you need where it says callback function, and it will be executed when the countdown is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this jQuery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html), the thing you want can be achieved by specifying the **onExpire** callback in options.

Comment: I wasnt using that countdown but ive have decided to change to that. I managed to get the expiration working, so that it goes to a differnet URL but my problem is now, that when someone goes back to the countdown page it just displays an countdown at 0. Any ideas how I can get to continually redirect when at 0? Thanks